# spring integration sftp unable to reconnect/configuration valid timeout

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have 2 OS: Windows 8.1(client with spring) and Debian 6 (server - virtual machine). I need test behavoir of spring sftp client when sftp server is unavailable due to network problem in 4 cases:

1. process on copying successfully working some time and I manually down eth0 at Debian. fixed-rate="10000" at int:poller
2. process on copying successfully working some time and I manually down eth0 at Debian. fixed-rate="1000" at int:poller
3. I manually down eth0 at Debian and try to start coping. fixed-rate="10000" at int:poller
4. I manually down eth0 at Debian and try to start coping.
   fixed-rate="1000" at int:poller

I see different behavoir when fixed-rate="1000" and when fixed-rate="10000".
The system works in a predictable when fixed-rate="10000" and unpredictable - fixed-rate="1000".
When fixed-rate="1000" I can't see any message at log file or at console after I down network adapter (debian: ifconfig eth0 down) on ftp server. I can wait around 1 hour - no message

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
               xmlns:int-sftp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp"
               xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp/spring-integration-sftp.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd">

            <int:message-history/>

            <bean id="defaultSftpSession" class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory">
                <property name="host" value="192.168.1.10"/>
                <property name="port" value="22"/>
                <property name="user" value="qqq"/>
                <property name="password" value="qqq"/>
            </bean>

            <bean id="sftpSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory">
                <constructor-arg ref="defaultSftpSession"/>
                <property name="poolSize" value="1"/>
            </bean>

            <int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="sftpInbondAdapter"
                                              channel="receiveChannel"
                                              session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
                                              local-directory="local-dir"
                                              remote-directory="/home/pen/testftp/1"
                                              auto-create-local-directory="true"
                                              delete-remote-files="false"
                                              preserve-timestamp="true"
                                              filter="compositeRemoteFilter"
                                              local-filter="compositeLocalFilter"
                    >
            <int:poller fixed-rate="1000" max-messages-per-poll="0"/>
            </int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>

            <int:channel id="receiveChannel">
                <int:queue/>
            </int:channel>

            <bean id="compositeRemoteFilter" class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.CompositeFileListFilter">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <list>
                        <bean class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.filters.SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter">
                            <constructor-arg name="store">
                                <bean class="org.springframework.integration.metadata.PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore">
                                    <property name="baseDirectory" value="mts_remote"/>
                                </bean>
                            </constructor-arg>
                            <constructor-arg name="prefix" value="f2/"/>
                        </bean>
                    </list>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>

            <bean id="compositeLocalFilter" class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.CompositeFileListFilter">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <list>
                        <bean class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter">
                            <constructor-arg name="store">
                                <bean class="org.springframework.integration.metadata.PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore">
                                    <property name="baseDirectory" value="mts_local"/>
                                </bean>
                            </constructor-arg>
                            <constructor-arg name="prefix" value="f1/"/>
                        </bean>
                    </list>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
        </beans>
```

log4j.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <!-- Appenders -->
    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p [%t][%c] %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="file1" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
        <param name="file" value="./log_1.out"/>
        <param name="immediateFlush" value="true"/>
        <param name="append" value="false"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p [%t][%c] %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="file2" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
        <param name="file" value="./log_2.out"/>
        <param name="immediateFlush" value="true"/>
        <param name="append" value="false"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p [%t][%c] %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <!-- Loggers -->
    <logger name="org.springframework">
        <level value="debug"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework.integration">
        <level value="debug"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework.integration.samples">
        <level value="debug"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="log4j.category.com.jcraft.jsch">
        <level value="debug"/>
        <appender-ref ref="file2"/>
    </logger>

    <root>
        <priority value="debug" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
        <appender-ref ref="file2" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Ouput (last string before eth0 down):

```
11:13:00.269 INFO  [task-scheduler-3][com.jcraft.jsch] Authentication succeeded (password).
11:13:00.289 DEBUG [task-scheduler-3][org.springframework.integration.util.SimplePool] Obtained new org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession@2459c07e.
11:13:00.292 DEBUG [task-scheduler-3][org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory] Releasing Session org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession@2459c07e back to the pool.
11:13:00.292 DEBUG [task-scheduler-3][org.springframework.integration.util.SimplePool] Removing org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession@2459c07e from the pool
11:13:00.292 INFO  [task-scheduler-3][com.jcraft.jsch] Disconnecting from 192.168.1.10 port 22
11:13:00.292 DEBUG [task-scheduler-3][org.springframework.integration.sftp.inbound.SftpInboundFileSynchronizer] 0 files transferred
11:13:00.292 INFO  [Connect thread 192.168.1.10 session][com.jcraft.jsch] Caught an exception, leaving main loop due to Socket closed
11:13:00.293 DEBUG [task-scheduler-3][org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter] Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
11:13:00.294 INFO  [task-scheduler-3][com.jcraft.jsch] Connecting to 192.168.1.10 port 22
11:13:00.295 INFO  [task-scheduler-3][com.jcraft.jsch] Connection established
11:13:00.300 INFO  [task-scheduler-3][com.jcraft.jsch] Remote version string: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6+squeeze2
11:13:00.300 INFO  [task-scheduler-3][com.jcraft.jsch] Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.51
11:13:00.300 INFO  [task-scheduler-3][com.jcraft.jsch] CheckCiphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256
11:13:00.301 INFO  [task-scheduler-3][com.jcraft.jsch] aes256-cbc is not available.
11:13:00.301 INFO  [task-scheduler-3][com.jcraft.jsch] aes192-cbc is not available.
11:13:00.301 INFO  [task-scheduler-3][com.jcraft.jsch] CheckKexes: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
11:13:00.314 INFO  [task-scheduler-3][com.jcraft.jsch] SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
11:13:00.315 INFO  [task-scheduler-3][com.jcraft.jsch] SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received
11:13:00.315 INFO  [task-scheduler-3][com.jcraft.jsch] kex: server: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
11:13:00.315 INFO  [task-scheduler-3][com.jcraft.jsch] kex: server: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
11:13:00.315 INFO  [task-scheduler-3][com.jcraft.jsch] kex: server: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
11:13:00.315 INFO  [task-scheduler-3][com.jcraft.jsch] kex: server: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
11:13:00.315 INFO  [task-scheduler-3][com.jcraft.jsch] kex: server: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
11:13:00.315 INFO  [task-scheduler-3][com.jcraft.jsch] kex: server: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
11:13:00.315 INFO  [task-scheduler-3][com.jcraft.jsch] kex: server: none,zlib@openssh.com
11:13:00.315 INFO  [task-scheduler-3][com.jcraft.jsch] kex: server: none,zlib@openssh.com
11:13:00.315 INFO  [task-scheduler-3][com.jcraft.jsch] kex: server: 
11:13:00.315 INFO  [task-scheduler-3][com.jcraft.jsch] kex: server: 
11:13:00.315 INFO  [task-scheduler-3][com.jcraft.jsch] kex: client: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
11:13:00.315 INFO  [task-scheduler-3][com.jcraft.jsch] kex: client: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
11:13:00.316 INFO  [task-scheduler-3][com.jcraft.jsch] kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc
11:13:00.316 INFO  [task-scheduler-3][com.jcraft.jsch] kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc
11:13:00.316 INFO  [task-scheduler-3][com.jcraft.jsch] kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
11:13:00.316 INFO  [task-scheduler-3][com.jcraft.jsch] kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
11:13:00.316 INFO  [task-scheduler-3][com.jcraft.jsch] kex: client: none
11:13:00.316 INFO  [task-scheduler-3][com.jcraft.jsch] kex: client: none
11:13:00.316 INFO  [task-scheduler-3][com.jcraft.jsch] kex: client: 
11:13:00.316 INFO  [task-scheduler-3][com.jcraft.jsch] kex: client: 
11:13:00.316 INFO  [task-scheduler-3][com.jcraft.jsch] kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
11:13:00.316 INFO  [task-scheduler-3][com.jcraft.jsch] kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
11:13:00.318 INFO  [task-scheduler-3][com.jcraft.jsch] SSH_MSG_KEXDH_INIT sent
11:13:00.318 INFO  [task-scheduler-3][com.jcraft.jsch] expecting SSH_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
11:13:00.323 INFO  [task-scheduler-3][com.jcraft.jsch] ssh_rsa_verify: signature true
11:13:00.324 INFO  [task-scheduler-3][com.jcraft.jsch] Host '192.168.1.10' is known and mathces the RSA host key
11:13:00.324 INFO  [task-scheduler-3][com.jcraft.jsch] SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
11:13:00.324 INFO  [task-scheduler-3][com.jcraft.jsch] SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS received
11:13:00.324 INFO  [task-scheduler-3][com.jcraft.jsch] SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
11:13:00.324 INFO  [task-scheduler-3][com.jcraft.jsch] SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
```

What is wrong with my configuration? 
What is simples way for error logging?

Comment: What is the root logger category level? What about `org.springframework`?

Comment: I update configuration several days ago. Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: You need to describe your problem more clearly.

Comment: I find interesting behaviour - when fixed-rate="10000" at <int:poller/> - I receive error. But when fixed-rate="1000" at <int:poller/> - no error.
Additionally I find reconnect time - 20sec when  fixed-rate="10000". Can I change this parameters?